# Convert printed graph into Excel data

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

Is there a way to transfer a line chart from paper to Excel formulas? I have a chart where I need to find x and y values from the graph:

[image: Graph]

I would like to convert values from the chart into formulas.

For simple charts it is possible to get an equation for the line, but in this case there are too many lines.

Comment: I think all the lines have similar formula and they differ only in parameters, if you've their formula then you can easily change those parameters (if you get stuck, then just post the formulas you've and we help writing it in Excel). However Excel can't find the formula for the lines.

Comment: There are programs, sort of like OCR for graphs, that will translate the lines from a graph image to either points or vectors.  That, at least, gets it into data that you can do something with.  However, I doubt that those programs could make useful sense out of something as complex as your example.

Comment: You might want to ask on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/